# If $G/K\cong H/K$ must $G\cong H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let K be a normal subgroup of $H$ and $G$ so that $G/K$ is isomorphic to $H/K$, must we have $G\cong H$?

I can't really tell you what I have tries since I haven't really done anything worth telling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that $G$ and $H$ both contain $K$, or do you mean that $G$ contains a normal subgroup which is isomorphic to a normal subgroup of $H$, namely $K$?

Comment: G and H both contain K.

Comment: With some fiddling, those two are essentially the same question, @MichaelAlbanese.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I am aware of that, but it wasn't clear to me that the OP was.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Define "fiddling". Is it possible to do this so that the "supergroup" containing both $G$, $H$ and $K$ is gauranteed to be finite for $G$, $H$ and $K$ finite? (You could take a free product with amalgamation, but this is infinite.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is false. Let $G=C_4, H=V_4, K=C_2$.

Comment: oh lol, I can't believe I didn't think of that. since both are abelian $C_2$ is normal to both, also the quotient is of prime order so it is $C_2$ right? thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's right!

Comment: This shows why it’s useful to spend a lot of time examining examples. No theorems to learn, just look at one special case after another, and understand each time what’s going on.

Comment: yes, this lesson has served me well, in this case these where very easy to understand, however I seem to have some trouble with other examples since I'm taking many of the courses from which the examples come simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample:

Let $A = {\mathbb Z}_4 \times {\mathbb Z}_2$, and let $G$ and $H$ be the subgroups of $A$ given by ${\mathbb Z}_4 \times \{0\}$ and $\langle 2\rangle \times {\mathbb Z}_2$ respectively. Now let $K = \langle 2\rangle \times  \{0\}$ which is a normal subgroup of both $G$ and $H$.

Answer (score 3):

A neat example is $S_3$. This group is the semidirect-product of the cyclic group of order two with the cyclic group of order three.
$$S_3\cong C_3\rtimes C_2$$
However, it is *not* isomorphic to the cross product $C_3\times C_2\cong C_6$. (Note that I write $C_n$ for the cyclic group of order $n$, so $C_n\cong\mathbb{Z}_n$.)

More generally, if $G$ is a semidirect product $G=N\rtimes_{\phi}H$ where the automorphism $\phi$ of $N$ is not inner, then (in general), $G/N\cong H$ and we have the following.
$$
N\rtimes_{\phi}H\not\cong N\times H
$$
Combining this with the fact that $\frac{N\times H}{N}\cong H$ yields a large class of examples.

Other concrete examples are then easily found:

- $D_{2n}\cong C_n\rtimes C_2\not\cong C_2\times C_n$
- The fundamental group of the Klein bottle, which has presentation $\langle a, b; a^{-1}ba=b^{-1}\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.
- $\operatorname{O}(n)\cong \operatorname{SO}(n)\rtimes C_2\not\cong \operatorname{SO}(n)\times C_2$.

Generalising this idea, if you have a short exact sequence
$$
1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow H\rightarrow 1
$$
which does not [split](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) then, in general, $G\not\cong N\times H$ so you obtain a counter-example. This is another massive class of counter)examples. For example,
$$
1\rightarrow A_n\rightarrow S_n\rightarrow C_2\rightarrow 1$$
but $S_n\not\cong A_n\times C_2$.

Comment: Yeah counterexamples abound. Whenever there's more than one [semi]direct product of two groups etc. Illustrated with $C_4$ and $C_2$ in [example 3 here](http://www.weddslist.com/groups/building/sdp.html) gives 4 different groups! Actually [the failure of] this question is basically the extension problem, i.e. describing all extensions.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest possible counter example is also the first one you would check. The smallest groups of equal order which are non-isomorphic are of order $4$, and both are abelian. Each group of order $4$ must have an element of order $2$, and thus a subgroup of order $2$. The quotient in the above two groups would be a group of order $2$, thus isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Thanks, does this have to do with the extension problem?

Comment: You are welcome and no, not in any profitable way.